# Unit Testing JMS payload

Tags: java, testing, mockito, jms, spring-jms

I have some code that looks like the following:

```java
class MyClass {
    private JmsTemplate messageSender;

    public void doStuff(Domain object domainObject){
       ... //other stuff
       updateClient(domainObject);
    }
    ...
    private void updateClient(DomainObject domainObject){
        final String payload = buildMessageForObject(domainObject);
        messageSender.send(new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session sn) throws JMSException {
               return sn.createTextMessage(payload);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My JMS template is autowired by the Spring framework. The logic for `buildMessageForObject` is actually inlined, but if it weren't it would be private. **What I'd like to do is to make assertions against the message payload string.** It would be nice if the Spring JMSTemplate API had something like `jmsTemplate.sendTextMessage(String text)` so that I could make verifications against the mocked `jmsTemplate` in my tests, but there seems to be too many layers of indirection between me and the message, and I can't see anything in the API for JMSTemplate or MessageCreator that obviously helps me restructure it to make it testable. I'm using JUnit and Mockito, but I don't know of any way that Mockito would allow me to specify the behaviour of the created `MessageCreator`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The JMS API *does* have a method like you want. It is [javax.jms.JMSProducer.send(Destination, String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSProducer.html#send-javax.jms.Destination-java.lang.String-). However, you aren't using the JMS API directly. You're using Spring JMS which is a layer *on top of* the JMS API.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks.